# jQuery bind error "event is not defined"

Tags: jquery

Currently I'm doing something like this in markup

```
<input type="text" ONKEYPRESS="InputNumeric(event);" id="txtNumber" />
```

But I want to use the jQuery bind method instead for all the obvious reasons.

```
jQuery(function($)
{
    $("#txtNumber").bind("keyup", InputNumeric(event));
});
```

But when I try the above I get the below error

"event is not defined"

What should this syntax look like?

**EDIT**

The actual solution I got working is shown below.

```
$("#txtPriority").keypress(function (e) { InputInteger(e); });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($)
{
    $("#txtNumber").bind("keyup", function(event) {InputNumeric(event);});
});
```

Comment: Actually it should be:
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#txtNumber").bind("keyup", function(event) {InputNumeric(event);});
});

Comment: $(function () { 
is shorthand for $(document).ready()
jQuery(function($) {  
is the same thing in noConflict mode.

Answer (score 3):

looks like InputNumeric is an existing function that takes an event as parameter, In that case this should also work

`$("#txtNumber").bind("keyup",InputNumeric);`

Answer (score 2):

Arguments passed back via jquery callbacks are always implied, so simply writing the function name is enough.

```
$("#txtNumber").bind("keyup",InputNumeric);

function InputNumeric(event){
    $(event.target).dosomething(); // is the same as
    $(this).dosomething();
}
```

Example: http://www.sanchothefat.com/dev/sfhelp/jquery-args.html

Comment: This is also more helpful when you use for loops as functions should not be defined within loops.